# Как получить уникальный идентификатор компьютера?

Tags: windows, delphi, идентификация

Планирую собирать анонимную статистику использования программы на сервер и хочу иметь возможность группировать сессии с одной машины. Встал вопрос, как получить в меру уникальный идентификатор компьютера и/или пользователя компьютера, при этом соблюдая анонимность (т.е. например не получать имя учетки человека)?
Что-то типа серийного номера жесткого диска или процессора, чтобы при каждом запуске программы он был один и тот же. Редкие случаи смены железа опустим.

```
ComputerUID := ...
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Судя по вопросу про Delphi подразумевается использование OS Windows. Лично я бы записал в реестр, в ветку моего приложения сгенерированный при первом запуске GUID.

Таким образом вы гарантируете и уникальность и конфиденциальность.

Comment: Если проверять лицензию по этому идентификатору, то хакер его выловит и перепишет в патчер, и всё. Он должен быть вычисляем и желательно проверяем через ПО, иначе смысла в нем нет.

Comment: В вопросе речь идет об анонимной статистике а не о DRM

Comment: Можно генерировать GUID во время установки приложения. Для манипуляций с реестром могут понадобиться права администратора.

Answer (score 13):

Я бы использовал идентификатор материнской платы. Получить его можно с помощью WMI. [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497253/how-to-get-motherboard-id-or-serial-number-in-delphi) есть на enSO. Как написано в одном из предыдущих ответов, я бы его ещё и захешировал, чтобы усилить анонимность.

Не рекомендую использовать сетевые интерфейсы, т.к. в них могут скрываться интерфейсы виртуальных машин, которые имеют свойство менять MAC адреса. Поэтому надо либо как-то отличить "железный" интерфейс, от виртуального. Либо делать нечёткое сравнение по всем интерфейсам сразу. Но, на мой взгляд, овчинка выделки не стоит - есть более стабильные идентификаторы.

Comment: Сегодня натолкнулся на вот такой идентификатор на своей второй машине - `To be filled by O.E.M.`. Отсюда вопрос - насколько этот идентификатор может быть уникальным сам по себе ..

Comment: @KromStern, да уж, интересное наблюдение. Значит ID материноской платы нельзя считать уникальным, т.к. его банально может не быть. В таком случае возникает вопрос - а что тогда гарантировано уникальное и всегда заполнено? Сдаётся мне, что нет такой сущности, поэтому в результате придётся использовать комбинацию идентификаторов. В противном случае всегда есть риск, что что-то изменится(или не будет уникальным). Сравнивать всю эту группу сущностей придётся не четко, т.к. надо быть готовым к изменениям.

Answer (score 11):

> не получать имя учетки человека

[личную информацию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7643383/4827341) можно [хэшировать](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) разными [путями](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58626/4827341).

Answer (score 10):

MAC адрес сетевой карты (минимальный из всех, если в компе несколько интерфейсов).

Answer (score 8):

Я использовал несколько схем:

- Серийный номер HDD - использовал в программах, где нужна привязка к текущей машине без учета пользователей.
- Серийный номер HDD + User Name + Komputer Name - для привязки к пользователю, железе.
- Привязка по серийнику флешки + файл лицензии на ней.

С данных бралась хеш-сумма. Или шифровались неким образом.

Answer (score 5):

Серийник системного раздела через GetVolumeInformation()

Comment: И потом виртуалку с вашей прогой клонируют

Comment: Все так или иначе можно пропатчить, но это не значит что надо бросать программирование.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Печаль в том, что клонирование (sysprep) может (не проверял) его не менять, а вот другая прога - [запросто](http://rsdn.ru/?forum/winapi/440488), причепм без спроса. В итоге как под одним id могут оказаться несколько компов, так и один комп может нафлудить id'ами.

Comment: ок, по разделу если, то ещё лучше  - образ с вашей прогой клонировали в геймклубе или на сборке для предприятия.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать имя компьютера, это не уникальный идентификатор, но, можно к нему добавить несколько параметров. Имя процессора, имя видеокарты, версия ОС, имя ОС, количество ОЗУ, IP адрес, найти компьютер с такими же параметрами будет практически невозможно. Теперь чтобы это имело хоть какой-то приятный вид, а не тупо набор параметров ПК, можно использовать шифрование в SHA1, SHA224, SHA256 или подобную... Разве что, я бы не использовал в этой связке IP, так как много людей используют VPN. Также версию ОС тоже не нужно использовать, так как ОС регулярно обновляется, просто закомментируйте строчки с IP адресом и версией ОС.

Вот как это будет выглядеть на Python (Нужно будет установить wmi, pip install wmi):

```
import socket
import wmi
import hashlib

PC = wmi.WMI()
Processor = PC.Win32_Processor()[0]
VideoCard = PC.Win32_VideoController()[0]
OS = PC.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0]
OS_Name = OS.Name.encode('utf-8').split(b'|')[0]
OS_Version = ' '.join([OS.Version, OS.BuildNumber])
RAM = float(OS.TotalVisibleMemorySize) / 1048576 #KB в GB

PCInfo = socket.gethostname() + "\n" #Имя ПК
#PCInfo += socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) + "\n" #IP адрес
PCInfo += str(OS_Name) + "\n" #Название ОС
#PCInfo += str(OS_Version) + "\n" #Версия ОС
PCInfo += str(RAM) + "\n" #Объем ОЗУ
PCInfo += str(Processor.Name) + "\n" #Имя процессора
PCInfo += str(VideoCard.Name) #Имя видеокарты

print(PCInfo)
print(hashlib.sha1(PCInfo.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()) #Шифрование в SHA1
```

Comment: P.S. Понимаю, что вопрос был задан 6 лет назад, но сюда сих пор приходят люди, по этому этот ответ для них)))