# Получение уникального идентификатора компьютера

Tags: c++, windows, идентификация

Прочитал много разных источников на предмет того, как сгенерировать уникальный идентификатор для компьютера, в основном пишут - получи MAC адрес (это не подходит потому что его можно легко поменять)
или использовать WMI и про него пишут что он может быть поломан или отключен по этому тоже не подходит.

Нашел вот такую   функцию, не совсем понял, по моему тут не уникальный идентификатор т.е. часть переменных это просто название производителя .. а другая что процессор может .. а это уж точно не то что нужно.

```
static const char* cpuId()
{
    unsigned long s1 = 0;
    unsigned long s2 = 0;
    unsigned long s3 = 0;
    unsigned long s4 = 0;
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, 00h
        xor edx, edx
        cpuid
        mov s1, edx
        mov s2, eax
        mov eax, 01h
        xor ecx, ecx
        xor edx, edx
        cpuid
        mov s3, edx
        mov s4, ecx
    }

    static char buf[100];
    sprintf_s(buf, "%08X %08X %08X %08X", s1, s2, s3, s4);
    return buf;
}
```

Итак, какой самый верный способ получить уникальный идентификатор компьютера не используя WMI и не привязываясь к идентификатору жесткого диска или MAC адреса ..? (используя WMI я бы привязал идентификатор к ID процессора , видеокарты и материнской платы, т.е. эти данные хорошо бы получить без WMI )
(Решение ищу на языке C++ )
Так же идентификатор не должен поменяться при переустановке Windows

Comment: Смотрите тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1167900/398802

Comment: @dIm0n разве реестр не слишком легко поменять ? ( я пишу для windows по этому из вашей ссылки только это подходит (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid ) ), к тому же мне не нужно чтобы при переустановке windows идентификатор поменялся, что происходит с этим ключом реестра

Comment: Нормальную идентификацию можно произвести посредством TPM. [Device provisioning: Identity attestation with TPM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/device-provisioning-identity-attestation-with-tpm/) Но (судя по предыдущему вопросу) я сильно подозреваю, что это будет потерей времени.

Comment: @user7860670 такой вариант не подходит, TPM нету на целевой машине

Comment: посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1015604/205817

Comment: И еще один связанный вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434820

Comment: @Kromster и снова mac или WMI я же чётко написал в вопросе, что и интересует  способ без них

Comment: Лично из Qt я собирал подходящее доступное из QSysInfo, плюс MAC адреса сетевух, вычислял md5 от результата и это у меня было uid'ом машины. Для моей задачи хватило.

Comment: @Sheridan ну ещё один.. почему все так помешаны на MAC?? я же и в теме и в комментариях отписал что MAC не является подходящим способом идентификации, мне не нужно чтобы мою программу могли запустить на всех компьютерах просто поменяв MAC адрес

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не считаю дубликатом, ведь согласитесь мой вопрос более развёрнутый и не один в один.. да ответ из той темы возможно подходит мне, но вопрос другой